# Understanding Tensor Inputs & Transformations for use in an LSTM (dynamic RNN)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am building an LSTM style neural network in Tensorflow and am having some difficulty understanding exactly what input is needed and the subsequent transformations made by *tf.nn.dynamic_rnn* before it is passed to the *sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits* layer.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn

### Understanding the input

The input function is sending a feature tensor in the form

**[batch_size, max_time]**

However the manual states that input tensors must be in the form

**[batch_size, max_time, ...]**

I have therefore expanded the input with a 1d tensor to take the form

**[batch_size, max_time, 1]**

At this point the input does not break upon running, but I don't understand exactly what we have done here and suspect it may be causing the problems when calculating loss (see below).

### Understanding the Transformations

This expanded tensor is then the 'features' tensor used in the code below

```
LSTM_SIZE = 3
lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(LSTM_SIZE, forget_bias=1.0)
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, features, dtype=tf.float64)

#slice to keep only the last cell of the RNN
outputs = outputs[-1]

#softmax layer

with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
   W = tf.get_variable('W', [LSTM_SIZE, n_classes], dtype=tf.float64)
   b = tf.get_variable('b', [n_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0), dtype=tf.float64)

logits = tf.matmul(outputs, W) + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=labels))
```

This throws a value error at *loss*

dimensions must be equal, but are **[max_time, num_classes] and [batch_size]**

from https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/classification -

*A common use case is to have logits of shape [batch_size, num_classes] and labels of shape [batch_size]. But higher dimensions are supported.*

At some point in the process max_time and batch_size have been mixed up and I'm uncertain if its at input or during the LSTM. I'm grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the shape of the output of the tf.nn.dynamic_rnn. From its documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn:

outputs: The RNN output Tensor.

If time_major == False (default), this will be a Tensor shaped: [batch_size, max_time, cell.output_size].

If time_major == True, this will be a Tensor shaped: [max_time, batch_size, cell.output_size].

you are in the default case, so your `outputs` gas shape `[batch_size, max_time, output_size]`, and when performing `outputs[-1]` you obtain a tensor with shape `[max_time, output_size]`. Probably slicing with `outputs[:, -1]` should fix it.

Comment: Easy fix, love it!